# Mockbean issues

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mocking

I just do a simple test with `MockBean` but always found errors.  Everything has been done with JDK 13.

I have a class `Car`:

```
@Component
public class Car {
    private final Engine engine;
    private final Transmission transmission;

    @Autowired
    public Car(Engine engine, Transmission transmission) {
        this.engine = engine;
        this.transmission = transmission;
    }

    String display() {
        return "Engine = " + engine.getName() + "; tran = " + transmission.getName();
    }
}


@Configuration
@ComponentScan("test.mockbean.com")
public class Config {

    @Bean
    public Engine getEngine() {
        return new Engine("v8", 5);
    }

    @Bean
    public Transmission GetTransmission() {
        return new Transmission("sliding");
    }
}

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {Config.class})
public class CarTest {
     @Autowired
    ApplicationContext context;

    @Test
    public void testEngine() {
        Car car = context.getBean(Car.class);
        assertEquals(car.display(), "Engine = v8 5; tran = sliding");

    }
}
```

However I add mockEngine using mockBean

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {Config.class})
public class CarTest {

    @MockBean
    Engine mockEngine;

     @Autowired
    ApplicationContext context;

    @Test
    public void testEngine() {
        when(mockEngine.getName()).thenReturn("mock enginer");
        Car car = context.getBean(Car.class);
        assertEquals(car.display(), "Engine = v8 5; tran = sliding");

    }
}
```

Then I got huge errors.

```
C:\Users\lsqua\.jdks\openjdk-14.0.2\bin\java.exe -ea -Didea.test.cyclic.buffer.size=1048576 "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.2.3\lib\idea_rt.jar=49697:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.2.3\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.2.3\lib\idea_rt.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.2.3\plugins\junit\lib\junit5-rt.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.2.3\plugins\junit\lib\junit-rt.jar;C:\Users\lsqua\OneDrive\Desktop\codes\test_DI_withMockBean\target\test-classes;C:\Users\lsqua\OneDrive\Desktop\codes\test_DI_withMockBean\target\classes;C:\Users\lsqua\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\maven-compiler-plugin\3.8.1\maven-compiler-plugin-3.8.1.jar;C:\Users\lsqua\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\maven-plugin-api\3.0\maven-plugin-api-3.0.jar;C:\Users\lsqua\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\maven-model\3.0\maven-model-3.0.jar;C:\Users\lsqua\.m2\repository\org\sonatype\sisu\sisu-inject-plexus\1.4.2\sisu-inject-plexus-1.4.2.jar;C:\Users\lsqua\.m2\repository\org\sonatype\sisu\sisu-inject-bean\1.4.2\sisu-inject-bean-1.4.2.jar;C:\Users\lsqua\.m2\repository\org\sonatype\sisu\sisu-guice\2.1.7\sisu-guice-2.1.7-noaop.jar;C:\Users\lsqua\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\maven-artifact\3.0\maven-artifact-3.0.jar;C:\Users\lsqua\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\plexus\plexus-utils\2.0.4\plexus-utils-2.0.4.jar;C:\Users\lsqua\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\maven-core\3.0\maven-core-3.0.jar;C:\Users\lsqua\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\maven-settings\3.0\maven-settings-3.0.jar;C:\Users\lsqua\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\maven-settings-builder\3.0\maven-settings-builder-3.0.jar;C:\Users\lsqua\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\maven-repository-metadata\3.0\maven-repository-metadata-3.0.jar;C:\Users\lsqua\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\maven-model-builder\3.0\maven-model-builder-3.0.jar;C:\Users\lsqua\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\maven-aether-provider\3.0\maven-aether-provider-3.0.jar;C:\Users\lsqua\.m2\repository\org\sonatype\aether\aether-impl\1.7\aether-impl-1.7.jar;C:\Users\lsqua\.m2\repository\org\sonatype\aether\aether-spi\1.7\aether-spi-1.7.jar;C:\Users\lsqua\.m2\repository\org\sonatype\aether\aether-api\1.7\aether-api-1.7.jar;C:\Users\lsqua\.m2\repository\org\sonatype\aether\aether-util\1.7\aether-util-1.7.jar;C:\Users\lsqua\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\plexus\plexus-interpolation\1.14\plexus-interpolation-1.14.jar;C:\Users\lsqua\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\plexus\plexus-classworlds\2.2.3\plexus-classworlds-2.2.3.jar;C:\Users\lsqua\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\plexus\plexus-component-annotations\1.5.5\plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar;C:\Users\lsqua\.m2\repository\org\sonatype\plexus\plexus-sec-dispatcher\1.3\plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.3.jar;C:\Users\lsqua\.m2\repository\org\sonatype\plexus\plexus-cipher\1.4\plexus-cipher-1.4.jar;C:\Users\lsqua\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\shared\maven-shared-utils\3.2.1\maven-shared-utils-3.2.1.jar;C:\Users\lsqua\.m2\repository\commons-io\commons-io\2.5\commons-io-2.5.jar;C:\Users\lsqua\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\shared\maven-shared-incremental\1.1\maven-shared-incremental-1.1.jar;C:\Users\lsqua\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\plexus\plexus-java\0.9.10\plexus-java-0.9.10.jar;C:\Users\lsqua\.m2\repository\org\ow2\asm\asm\6.2\asm-6.2.jar;C:\Users\lsqua\.m2\repository\com\thoughtworks\qdox\qdox\2.0-M8\qdox-2.0-M8.jar;C:\Users\lsqua\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\plexus\plexus-compiler-api\2.8.4\plexus-compiler-api-2.8.4.jar;C:\Users\lsqua\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\plexus\plexus-compiler-manager\2.8.4\plexus-compiler-manager-2.8.4.jar;C:\Users\lsqua\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\plexus\plexus-compiler-javac\2.8.4\plexus-compiler-javac-2.8.4.jar;C:\Users\lsqua\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\5.2.9.RELEASE\spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\lsqua\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\5.2.9.RELEASE\spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\lsqua\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\5.2.9.RELEASE\spring-core-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\lsqua\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jcl\5.2.9.RELEASE\spring-jcl-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\lsqua\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\5.2.9.RELEASE\spring-expression-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\lsqua\.m2\repository\org\mockito\mockito-all\1.10.19\mockito-all-1.10.19.jar;C:\Users\lsqua\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\5.2.9.RELEASE\spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\lsqua\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\2.3.4.RELEASE\spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\lsqua\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\2.3.4.RELEASE\spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\lsqua\.m2\repository\junit\junit\4.12\junit-4.12.jar;C:\Users\lsqua\.m2\repository\org\hamcrest\hamcrest-core\1.3\hamcrest-core-1.3.jar;C:\Users\lsqua\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-test\5.2.9.RELEASE\spring-test-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\lsqua\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-test\2.3.4.RELEASE\spring-boot-test-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\lsqua\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\5.2.8.RELEASE\spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\lsqua\.m2\repository\org\mockito\mockito-core\3.2.4\mockito-core-3.2.4.jar;C:\Users\lsqua\.m2\repository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy\1.10.5\byte-buddy-1.10.5.jar;C:\Users\lsqua\.m2\repository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy-agent\1.10.5\byte-buddy-agent-1.10.5.jar;C:\Users\lsqua\.m2\repository\org\objenesis\objenesis\2.6\objenesis-2.6.jar" com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter -ideVersion5 -junit4 test.mockbean.com.CarTest
Oct 24, 2020 5:16:56 PM org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper buildDefaultMergedContextConfiguration
INFO: Neither @ContextConfiguration nor @ContextHierarchy found for test class [test.mockbean.com.CarTest], using SpringBootContextLoader
Oct 24, 2020 5:16:56 PM org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader generateDefaultLocations
INFO: Could not detect default resource locations for test class [test.mockbean.com.CarTest]: no resource found for suffixes {-context.xml, Context.groovy}.
Oct 24, 2020 5:16:57 PM org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper getDefaultTestExecutionListenerClassNames
INFO: Loaded default TestExecutionListener class names from location [META-INF/spring.factories]: [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.event.EventPublishingTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener]
Oct 24, 2020 5:16:57 PM org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper getTestExecutionListeners
INFO: Using TestExecutionListeners: [org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener@73a1e9a9, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener@71d44a3, org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@7b98f307, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener@4802796d, org.springframework.test.context.event.EventPublishingTestExecutionListener@34123d65, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener@59474f18]

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.3.4.RELEASE)

[2020-10-24 17:16:57.639] - 17348 INFO [main] --- test.mockbean.com.CarTest: Starting CarTest on DESKTOP-IGMGBVL with PID 17348 (started by lsqua in C:\Users\lsqua\OneDrive\Desktop\codes\test_DI_withMockBean)
[2020-10-24 17:16:57.666] - 17348 INFO [main] --- test.mockbean.com.CarTest: No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.mockito.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$2 (file:/C:/Users/lsqua/.m2/repository/org/mockito/mockito-all/1.10.19/mockito-all-1.10.19.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.mockito.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$2
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
[2020-10-24 17:16:58.799] - 17348 INFO [main] --- test.mockbean.com.CarTest: Started CarTest in 1.5 seconds (JVM running for 2.541)
[2020-10-24 17:16:58.824] - 17348 WARNING [main] --- org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager: Caught exception while invoking 'beforeTestMethod' callback on TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener@59474f18] for test method [public void test.mockbean.com.CarTest.testEngine()] and test instance [test.mockbean.com.CarTest@5215cd9a]
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.mockito.mock.MockCreationSettings org.mockito.MockingDetails.getMockCreationSettings()'
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockReset.get(MockReset.java:107)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.resetMocks(ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.java:81)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.resetMocks(ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.java:69)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.beforeTestMethod(ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.java:56)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.beforeTestMethod(TestContextManager.java:289)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)

[2020-10-24 17:16:58.829] - 17348 WARNING [main] --- org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager: Caught exception while invoking 'afterTestMethod' callback on TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener@59474f18] for test method [public void test.mockbean.com.CarTest.testEngine()] and test instance [test.mockbean.com.CarTest@5215cd9a]
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.mockito.mock.MockCreationSettings org.mockito.MockingDetails.getMockCreationSettings()'
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockReset.get(MockReset.java:107)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.resetMocks(ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.java:81)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.resetMocks(ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.java:69)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.afterTestMethod(ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.java:63)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.afterTestMethod(TestContextManager.java:441)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:94)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)


java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.mockito.mock.MockCreationSettings org.mockito.MockingDetails.getMockCreationSettings()'

    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockReset.get(MockReset.java:107)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.resetMocks(ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.java:81)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.resetMocks(ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.java:69)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.beforeTestMethod(ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.java:56)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.beforeTestMethod(TestContextManager.java:289)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)


java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.mockito.mock.MockCreationSettings org.mockito.MockingDetails.getMockCreationSettings()'

    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockReset.get(MockReset.java:107)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.resetMocks(ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.java:81)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.resetMocks(ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.java:69)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.afterTestMethod(ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.java:63)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.afterTestMethod(TestContextManager.java:441)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:94)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)


Process finished with exit code -1
```

Answer (score 1):

Just found the issue:

I add both mockito-core and mockito-all in the maven.
Somehow, mockito-all (still stuck at 1.10.19) overrides mockito-core.

Answer (score -1):

https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.2.7/org/mockito/MockingDetails.html#getMockCreationSettings()

> getMockCreationSettings MockCreationSettings<?>
> getMockCreationSettings() Returns various mock settings provided when
> the mock was created, for example: mocked class, mock name (if any),
> any extra interfaces (if any), etc. See also MockCreationSettings.
> This method is useful for framework integrators and for certain edge
> cases.
>
> If null or non-mock was passed to Mockito.mockingDetails(Object) then
> this method will throw with an appropriate exception. After all,
> non-mock objects do not have any mock creation settings.
>
> Since:
> 2.1.0

The problem is your version. You can check the current version of your package by
`show dependencies`.

[image]